# Memory Allocation Tracking in C -- Am I doing this right?

Tags: c, memory-management

Just for fun (and for C programming practice) I wrote the following piece of code that does the following:

- Acts as a tracking system for memory allocations
- Frees all dynamically allocated memory with a function call

Here is the code:

```
typedef enum _OpMode {
    OM_APPEND,
    OM_DESTROY
} OP_MODE;

void refOp(void *ptr, OP_MODE mode) {
    /* contains static array of pointers and provides an interface to that
       array */

    static void **references = NULL;
    static int size = 0;
    static int reset = 0;

    if (reset) {
        reset = 0;
        references = NULL;
        size = 0;
    }

    switch (mode) {
        case OM_APPEND:
            //add a pointer to reference array
            references = (void**) realloc(references, sizeof(void*) * (size + 1));
            references[size++] = ptr;
            break;
        case OM_DESTROY:
            //free memory at all pointers kept in reference array
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                free(references[i]);
                references[i] = NULL;
            }
            free(references);
            reset = 1;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid enum value '%d' passed as mode.\n", mode);
            break;
    }
}

void refDestroyAll() {
    //Wrapper function
    refOp(NULL, OM_DESTROY);
}

void *myAlloc(void* ptr, size_t size) {
    /* Allocates memory and stores pointer copy in reference array */
    void *tmp_ptr;
    tmp_ptr = realloc(ptr, size);
    refOp(tmp_ptr, OM_APPEND);
    return tmp_ptr;
}
```

The idea is that one would use `myAlloc()` instead of `malloc` or `realloc` to dynamically allocate memory. And one would use `refDestroyAll()` to free all memory that was created with `myAlloc()`.

I've done some testing, and it *seems* to be working, but I can't help feeling that I'm missing something important. Does this code actually work as intended, or am I leaking memory when I call `refDestroyAll()`?

Comment: Maybe you can trace the source code of some profiling tools, such as valgrind http://valgrind.org/.

Comment: For what you're doing, just running valgrind itself on your code will let you know if you're leaking memory from `refDestroyAll()` ... you don't need to inspect the source-code of valgrind.

Comment: @qrtt1: Thanks for the valgrind link. I'm just testing out my program now.

Comment: @Jason: Ran valgrind on a _very_ simple use case. Seems to be working so far... I'm new to C (coming from a Python background) and I guess I'm just curious to know if what I'm doing is conceptually sound.

Comment: Repeatedly calling realloc() to grow a memory block by a small increment is very wasteful. It works, but with most memory allocators out there you have a O(n^2) cost for doing so due to memory copies. Sure that cost may have a very small factor due to performance of modern realloc, but still it has bad code smell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bug, that could cause a segmentation fault. `realloc()` could return the same pointer as it is given, in which case you would have added it twice to the array. When you call your free function, it would try and free the same pointer twice, resulting in a segmentation fault error.

Additionally, I don't understand why you have the reset parameter. Why not simply set references and size to 0 in the `OM_DESTROY` case? It is good practice to always set a pointer to NULL **immediately** after freeing it.

Comment: So you're saying that if I perform `myAlloc` on the same array twice, and then call `refDestroyAll`, it will segfault while freeing the second reference to that pointer?

Comment: I'm thinking I could fix this by defining two alloc functions `myMalloc` (replaces `malloc`) and `myRealloc` (replaces `realloc`). That way, I only add an item to references from `myRealloc` if the pointer values are not equal. Does this sound reasonable, or am I still missing the point? Also your right about the reset parameter, it's unnecessary.

Comment: That would work, but it has the potential to slow a really large program down, as you will have to perform an O(n) search through the array each time you call realloc.